# GridSearchCV/RandomizedSearchCV with partial_fit in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, hyperparameters

As per the documentation of [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) and [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) modules of sklearn, they support only the `fit` method for the classifier which is passed to them and doesn't support the `partial_fit` method of the classifiers which can be used for training on an incremental basis. Currently, I am trying to use `SGDClassifier` which can be trained on incremental data using the `partial_fit` method and also find the best set of hyper-parameters for the same. I was just wondering why doesn't `RandomizedSearchCV` or `GridSearchCV` support `partial_fit`. I don't see any technical reasons as to why this cannot be done (please correct me if I am wrong here). Any leads will be really appreciated.

Comment: It's just not implemented because the majority of the sklearn models do not support `partial_fit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, technically you can write a GridSerachCV for `partial_fit` as well, but when you think about

- what is that you are searching for?
- what is that your are optimizing for?

it becomes quite different from what we do with the `.fit()` approach. Here is my list of reason for not having `partial_fit` in `GridsearchCV`/`RandomSearchCV`.

> what is that you are searching for?

1. When we optimize for the hyper parameters of a model for one batch of data, it could be sub-optimal for the final model (which is trained on complete data using multiple `partial_fit`s). Now the problem becomes finding the best schedule for the hyper parameters i.e. what is the optimal value of the hyper parameter at each batch/time step. One example of this is the decaying learning rate in neural networks, where we train the model using multiple `partial_fit`s and the hyper parameter - learning rate value would not be a single value but a series values that needs to be used for each time step/batch.
2. Also you need to loop through the entire dataset multiple times (multiple epochs) to know the best scheduling of the hyper parameters. This needs a basic API change for GridSearchCV.

> what is that your are optimizing for?

3. There is a need to change the evaluation metric of the model now. The metric could be achieving best performance at the end of all `partial_fit`s or reaching the sweet-spot quickly (in fewer batches) for usual metric (`precision`, `recall`, `f1-score`, etc.), some combination of one and two. Hence, this also needs a API change for computing the single value for summarizing the performance of a model, which was trained using multiple `partial_fit`s.

Comment: How would other hyperparameters (such as regularization coefficients) be chosen? Would you need to have an outer loop over all the hyperparameter values and the inner loop making multiple calls to `partial_fit`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved in a different way. I have encontered the problem that only `partial_fit` works (data is too big to do full batch learning via `fit`), so I think scikit-learn should have `partial_fit` support somewhere.

Instead of having `partial_fit` in `GridSearchCV`, you can write a simple wrapper (something like a pytorch `DataLoader`) which turns a `partial_fit` model into `fit` model, and do batch split and shuffle inside the wrapper's `fit`. Then you can make `GridSearchCV` work, with extra parameter to be fine-tuned provided by the wrapper (`batch_size` and `is_shuffle`)